# how to bind data to select2 jquery from database in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, multi-select

View:

```
<select multiple="" id="e2" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" name="e2" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="PDS.RICE">PDS.RICE</option>
    <option value="PDS.WHEAT">PDS.WHEAT</option>
    <option value="PDS.DAL CHANNA">PDS.DAL CHANNA</option>
    <option value="PDS.DAL KALA CHANNA">PDS.DAL KALA CHANNA</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Getitems()
{
    var items = (from m in db.ItemMasters select m).ToList();
    ViewBag.items = items;
    return View();
}
```

Model:

```
public class ItemMaster
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the data from database in the controller, but unable to bind the `ViewBag` data to the `select2-hidden-accessible` in view.

Comment: What have you tried? And why are you not using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` and strongly bind to a model?

Comment: i have tried @Html.DropDownListFor(), but did not get the solution.

Comment: Interesting - works for me and millions of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind dropdownlist by using ViewBag, below is the code :

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Getitems()
        {
            var itemList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "RICE",
                Value = "RICE"
                },
                 new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "WHEAT",
                Value = "WHEAT"
                }
            };



            ViewBag.ItemList = new SelectList(itemList, "Value", "Text");
            return View();
        }
```

View :

Add below scripts in your head tag.

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

 @Html.DropDownList("e2", (SelectList) ViewBag.ItemList, new {@class = "js-example-basic-multiple",multiple="multiple" })
```

Initialize the select2 plugin.

```
<script>
        $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>
```

Comment: It's a tried and tested code. What exactly you did with the above code?

Comment: I have edited my answer please check now and mark as answer if your issue is resolved.

Comment: hi i tried your code but not working for me any work around?

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: View:
`@Html.DropDownList("e2", (SelectList)ViewBag.ItemList, new { @class = "select2-hidden-accessible" })
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#e2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Commodity",
        allowClear: true
    });
</script>`

Comment: basically the select2 jquery multiselect is not showing in case og multiplelistitem its showing basic multiselect

Comment: Can you check with the above code. i have made the changes.